# Using ArgumentCaptor on a static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm using Mockito and PowerMock for unit tests. I've got a method under test that looks something like this:

```
public void underTest(MyClass obj, int num) {
  String arg = "";
  if (obj.conditionIsTrue(num)) {
    arg = "foo";
  } else {
    arg = "bar";
  }
  StaticClass.staticMethod(arg);
}
```

I want to verify the argument to `staticMethod()`, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I know how to use `ArgumentCaptor` when I have an actual mock object to work on:

```
@Mock private MyClass mockObject;
@Captor ArgumentCaptor<MyClass> captor;

@Test
public void Test1() {
  underTest(mockObject, 1);
  verify(mockObject).conditionIsTrue(captor.capture());
  assertEquals(1, captor.getValue());
}
```

But how do I do the same thing on the argument to `staticMethod`?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review this  https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method

Comment: Take a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/4SzUWkytP2E

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for anyone stumbling across it (like I did):

1. from 3.4.0 Mockito can mock static methods, look to the MockStatic class for details.
2. The capture fails because of times(): verify focuses first on counting the number of times, and it can't capture from potentially multiple calls.